# What should I do to solve my problem with dropna and fillna in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I see there are some missing data, in my data. 
there are NaN values in "Type 2" column.

[image: you see NaN values here]

When i write this code to drop the rows which have NaN values;

[image: its after using dropna]

When i write this code to add "empty" which have NaN values;

[image: and this one ater using fillna]

I restarted my jupyter notebook but its still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `data['Type 2'].dropna(inplace=True)`, that's creating a new series (for your "Type 2" column) and dropping the nans from that new data structure. It doesn't change your original dataframe.

If you want to dropna from the DataFrame, you need to do it directly on that object, not on the column object. The following drops nans directly on the DataFrame:

```py
data.dropna(subset=['Type 2'], inplace=True)
```

Note that here we're calling `dropna` on `data` directly. `subset` is the argument that you can use to tell pandas which columns to use to determine which rows to drop.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are amazing! i understand now

Comment: can you help me with my fillna  problem too? i couldnt get it worked

Comment: i get it worked by this code data.fillna("empty",inplace=True), it writes "empty" to whereever it finds NaN value, but what if i only want to do it in "Type 2" column, how could i code it?

Comment: sorry i wrote too much, but now i see it works, data["Type 2"].fillna("empty",inplace=True)
data.head(10) i dont know why it didnt work before

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
data = data[data['Type 2'].notna()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`data.dropna(axis=1, inplace=True)`

axis=1 means columns axis=0 means rows
if any column contains NaN it will remove entire column similarly row

Comment: thank you, data.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True) works but why didnt my code work? i just wanted to do the same by using the Type 2 column.

Comment: @Semih because every column must have to equal number of rows, what you were doing is removing the block which has Nan which makes number of row unequal.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one to fill your data

```
data = data.ffill().bfill()
```